# Process file If FileExists And 2nd FileExists

Tags: vbscript

`Ok, I was asked to be more specific in my question.  I have an undetermined number of files in my folder, for example:

1. NV_A1_mainx.dxf
2. NV_A1_resx.dxf
3. NV_B1_mainx.dxf
4. NV_B1_motx.dxf
5. NV_B1_motlx.dxf

The folder is Looped processing each file based on the InStr "mainx”, “motx”, or “resx”.  On “motx” type files I want the script to search and see if there additional matching type file “motlx”.  If there is it will process one way.  If not it will process a second way.  The filenames will be different however the filename convention will always have two underscores “_” followed by the InStr characters I search on.

Using the files above as an example, I wish to write a statement so that when NV_A1_motx.dxf  is about to be processed it will check to see if there is a matching NV_B1_motlx.dxf in the folder.

The problem is the last line of my script. How do I write that statement correctly for "motx" to see if there is also a "motlx" file present in the folder?

Thx... hope that clarifies better my intentions.

```
Set App = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("S:\SOCAL\Section_13\Road DXFs")
Set DXFfile = SourceFolder.Files
Set DXFfolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)                                  


Dim FileRef
For Each FileRef In SourceFolder.Files
   If Instr(FileRef,"motx") > 0 then
       Call Motx(FileRef)
   ElseIf Instr(FileRef,"mainx") > 0 then
       Call Mainx(FileRef)
   ElseIf Instr(FileRef,"resx") > 0 then
   Call Resx(FileRef)
   Else
       Msgbox "File is not being found or some issue with script."
   End If
Next

Sub Motx(FileRef)

If ((App.Documents.Count > 0) And (FileExists("S:\SOCAL\Section_13\Road DXFs\SOCAL_B2_motlx.dxf"))) Then
Else
```

Thank you for your input Jose.  I was getting errors plugging the code in so what I did was just strip the code to the basics to see if your code would find the matching files.  What I did was in the folder have just two files:

NV_B2_motlx.dvx and 
NV_B2_motx.dvx

Testing with your script as so:

```
Set App = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("S:\SOCAL\Section_13\Road DXFs")
Set DXFfile = SourceFolder.Files
Set DXFfolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)

For Each FileRef In SourceFolder.Files
    ' default property of `FileRef` object is `Path`
    If Instr( FileRef.Name, "motx", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
   I    f fso.FileExists( fso.BuildPath( fso.GetParentFolderName( objFile.Path), _
             Replace( FileRef.Name, "motx", "motlx", 1, -1, vbTextCompare))) Then
           'motlx' exists
           MsgBox "We have a match!"
       Else
           'motlx' does not exist
           MsgBox "Sorry, no match"
       End If
    End If
Next
```

Running this I got the following error message: Type mismatch:'[string:"NV_B2_motlx.dxf"]' Code 800A000D Line 9 Char 5.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add  reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can. Too broad as currently written: _… based on its filename_ How based? a particular substring elsewhere? or starting substring? regex-based match? the same rule for both files? or related rules? or independent rules? or do you have a list of filename pairs? **etc. etc.**

Comment: And query of possibly highest importance: what-if there are more (1+) files matching 1st-type criteria **and** more (2+) files  matching 2nd-type criteria, then … process each 1st one for each 2nd? … or process each 1st  one once regardless of 2nd count? … or another order? Please give such rule.

Comment: Even with your newly added information, I'm not able to udnerstand what your problem is, because you don't mention it, in a single sentence. What is your actual problem?

Comment: The problem is the last line of my script.  How do I write that statement correctly for "motx" to see if there is also a "motlx" file present in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code stub could help:

```
Dim FileRef
For Each FileRef In SourceFolder.Files
    ' default proprty of `FileRef` object is `Path`
    If Instr( FileRef.Name, "motx", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       If fso.FileExists( fso.BuildPath( fso.GetParentFolderName( objFile.Path), _
             Replace( FileRef.Name, "motx", "motlx", 1, -1, vbTextCompare))) Then
           'motlx' exists
       Else
           'motlx' does not exist
       End If
```

Reference:

- [Functions (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ca8tfek(v=vs.84).aspx): `InStr`, `Replace`
- [FileSystemObject Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea5ht6ax(v=vs.84).aspx): `.Name`, `.Path`
- [FileSystemObject Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx): `.BuildPath`, `.GetParentFolderName`